# How to change the display position of the options in React Draft Wysiwyg RTE

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, wysiwyg, rte

Using React Draft Wysiwyg RTE in my application. Displaying toolbar inside a modal, so need to display the dropdown options of "Font-Family" towards at top

Tried applying menuTopPlacement as top and it doesn't work. Applied overflow as visibility to the options wrapper and it also not as expected.

[image: Screenshot - Font family options with default placement]